# How to open a URL in the same window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am using this code currently and it works great. I am now wanting it to open the url in the same window instead of in a new window. I've read up on this and tried "_self" and I must be doing something wrong.

This is a sample of the code.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Radio Window </TITLE>
<script>
  function OpenWindow(){
    for(i=0;i<document.FormName["RB1"].length;i++){
      if(document.FormName["RB1"][i].checked){
    window.open(document.FormName["RB1"][i].value);
    break;
  }
}
  }
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <form name="FormName">
    <input type="radio" name="RB1" value="http://www10.brinkster.com/A1ien51" checked>Eric's Webpage<BR>
<input type="radio" name="RB1" value="http://www.javaranch.com">JavaRanch<BR>
<input type="radio" name="RB1" value="http://www.google.com">Google<BR>
<input type="button" value="Open New Window" name="butt" onclick="OpenWindow()">
  </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If you mean that you want another page to replace the current page don't use `window.open()` at all, just set `location.href = ...`

Comment: Do you mean you want to open a new tab within the same window?

Comment: No, I want to use the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `action='url of page you want to open'` in your form tag and it would work.

like change this `<form name="FormName"> to <form name="FormName" action='url'>`

Also replace your last input with this in the form `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: These modifications do not work for me. What I'm looking for is like i was to go to the top of the page and enter "google.com" in the address bar instead of opening a new tab. I am adding this code in wix using the html drag and drop app. If not careful the code tries to open the url inside my little form box instead of a what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to change the current page location, so you can do so by changing your function like this :

```
function OpenWindow() {
  var inputs = document.forms.FormName["RB1"];
  for (var i = 0; i <inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      document.location.assign(inputs[i].value);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

See the documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Location/assign